Find discontinuities of $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}x$
Consider this function:
$$f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}x$$
I want to find the discontinuous point of this function, which means I first have to solve the limit, here is my approach:
From this equation:
$$a^n - 1 = (a-1) (a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + ...+a+1)$$
I can rewrite the limit as such:
$$-\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(x-1)(x^{2n-1}+x^{2n-2}+...+x+1)}{x^{2n}+1}x$$
Multiply the $x$ in, I get:
$$-\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(x-1)(x^{2n}+x^{2n-1}+...+x^2+x)}{x^{2n}+1}$$
But now I am stuck with my approach, can anyone help me with next step? Any help is appreciated!

Do you know the limit of $x^{2n}$? $f(x)=x$ for $|x|<1$, $f(x)=-x$ for $|x|>1$. $f(x)=0$ for $x =\pm 1$.

@geetha290krm, I have no idea about this limit, could you elaborate on it?

When $|x| < 1$ the exponentiated terms will go to $0$ as $n$ becomes large.  If $|x|>1$ they will grow do dominate the constants when $n$ is large.

So when $|x| <1$, the limit will be $0$ and when $|x|>1$, the limit will be $\infty$?

Perhaps it would prove more fruitful to write the numerator a tad differently...
$$
\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}x
= \frac{1+x^{2n}-2x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}x
= \left( 1 - \frac{2x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} \right)x
$$
...and then divide the top and bottom by $x^{2n}$:
$$
\left( 1 - \frac{2x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} \right)x
= \left( 1 - \frac{2 }{\displaystyle 1+\frac{1}{x^{2n}}} \right)x
$$
Now perhaps it's a tad more obvious what the limit should be: by various limit laws,
$$
f(x) = \left( 1 - \frac{2 }{\displaystyle  1+\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{x^{2n}}} \right)x
$$
Now we can pull back to our ideas from geometric series:

Notice that $x^{2n} = (x^2)^n$, so we don't have to worry about signs too much in the sense of worrying about divergence/oscillatory behavior.
What happens if $-1 < x < 1$?
What happens if $x=-1$?
What happens if $x<-1$?
What happens if $x=1$?
What happens if $x>1$?

Try a few values of $x$ or look at a graph if you're unsure.

The graph of $g(x) = x^{-2n}$ for various $n$ looks like this:

The graph of $f$ for various $n$ looks like this:

Both are viewable in this Desmos demo.
